# Guice inject null check?

Tags: java, guice, inject

I am using google guice inject at the constructor level. Does it make sense to do a null check on the parameters to ensure they are not null or inject does that for us. Btw, its a public constructor.

What about public method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you *happen* to be using Guice to call the constructor in some cases doesn't mean anything else is prohibited from calling it.

Personally, I would include the nullity checks - which are very light on cruft if you're using Guava as well. For example:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

class Player implements SomeInterface {
    private final String name;

    @Inject
    Player(String name) {
        this.name = checkNotNull(name);
    }

    ...
}
```

Aside from anything else, I'd expect some of your *tests* to be calling the constructor directly - and it's useful to find any bugs in your tests as early as possible, just like other code. It also expresses your intent clearly to anyone else who comes along later.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that in most cases, `@Inject`-annotated constructors aren't recommended to be `public`: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/KeepConstructorsHidden

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Good call. Made both the class and the constructor package-private, and implemented an interface...

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the comments both of you.
I read this documentation of guice - "Guice forbids null by default. It will refuse to inject null, failing with a ProvisionException instead. If null is permissible by your class, you can annotate the field or parameter with @Nullable"- 
https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UseNullable

So you think this documentation maybe incorrect?

Comment: @ND27: No, not at all. I'm saying that just because *Guice* won't call your `Player` constructor doesn't mean that no other code will... and that it's best to validate it.